# Mirroring a WordPress site with wget

Tags: wget, wordpress

I'm trying to mirror a WordPress site that is no longer updated so that I can remove the php backend.  I have no desire to worry about updating the site again.  I realize this will break dynamic parts such as search and comments and I'm ok with that loss of functionality.  If there's a better way to do this, I'm open to other suggestions beyond wget.

I am currently using the following command.

```
wget -vN --server-response --wait=6 --domains=example.com --exclude-directories=admin --mirror --random-wait=on http://example.com -o ~/exampleFetch.log
```

The problem is that some pages are not being saved and wget is outputting the following error.

```
Cannot write to "example.com/archives/2009/09/16/example-post-title" (Not a directory).
```

This is because there are links to archived months on the main page that list all posts for a given month.  For instance:

```
example.com/archives/2009/09
```

is saved as a *file* locally by wget, because

```
http://example.com/archives/2009/09/
```

does return a sensible page.

Hopefully I'm missing a switch or have misunderstood one.  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should edit your .htaccess file to turn the Rewrite engine off while mirroring.  You'll have strangely named files, but you shouldn't have any conflicts in naming.

Comment: Thanks. This would indeed work, but I would prefer to use it as a last resort.

Ideally, I was hoping the directories like 2005/11/ would get saved like 2005/11/index.html so that subdirectories could be made inside. Though, I wasn't quite clear on that in my original post.

Comment: If that's the case you'll probably need some bash renaming magic and a few passes.  But you can manually do it.  Something like for i in {2005..2011}; do mv $i $i.temp; mkdir $i; mv $i.temp $i/index.html; done

Answer (score 1):

I think if you use the --html-extension option it will make pages (with a .html extension!) for each of those folder named pages.

I followed [these instructions](http://darcynorman.net/2011/12/24/archiving-a-wordpress-website-with-wget/) to mirror my wordpress blog and they worked well.